# How do I hide the "next" button on the last page in a table

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to implement pagination for my table. I have already implemented the "next" and "previous" buttons which work fine. The "previous" button is not displayed on the first page, only after which is correct. But the only issue I'm facing right now is when I'm on the last page, I don't want to display the "next" button. How do I implement this?

```
function App() {
  const [apiData, setApiData] = useState([]);
  const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState(); // Default = No search query
  const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(1); //Default = Page 1
  const [postsPerPage, setPostsPerPage] = useState(10); //Default 10 result per page 
  
  let apiQuery = "api";
  

  useEffect(() => {
    // All parameters are appended to this URL.
    let apiQuery = "api";
    
    // Add what page we are requesting to the API request.
    apiQuery = apiQuery + "&page=" + pageNumber;
    apiQuery = apiQuery + "&pageSize=" + postsPerPage;

    console.log("posts: " , postsPerPage);
    
    // Query data from API.
    console.log("Querying: " + apiQuery);
    fetch(apiQuery)
      .then((results) => results.json())
      .then((data) => {
        // Then add response to state.
        setApiData(data);
      });
 
  }, [pageNumber, postsPerPage]); // Array containing which state changes that should re-reun useEffect()

  const search=()=>{

    // If searchQuery isn't empty add &search=searchQuery to the API request.
    if (searchQuery) {
      apiQuery = apiQuery + "&search=" + searchQuery;
    }

    // setting data as required, same as in the useEffect
    fetch(apiQuery).then(result=>result.json()).then(data=>setApiData(data))
  
  }
 const totalPages = Math.ceil(apiData.length / postsPerPage);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Country lookup</h1>
      <input value={searchQuery} onChange={(e) => setSearchQuery(e.target.value)} />
      <button onClick={search}>Search</button> 
      <select value={postsPerPage} onChange={(event) => setPostsPerPage(event.target.value)}>
      <option value={10}>10</option>
      <option value={20}>20</option>
      <option value={50}>50</option>
      </select>
      <Table apiData={apiData} />
```

These are the next and previous buttons I implemented. The whole code is in one file.

```
            <nav>
                {pageNumber!==1 && <button onClick={()=>setPageNumber(pageNumber-1)}>Previous page</button>}
                {!apiData.length? pageNumber!== !apiData.length &&<button onClick={()=>setPageNumber(pageNumber+1)}>Next page</button>:""}
            </nav>


    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The condition you are looking for is:

```
{pageNumber < totalPages() && (<button>...</button>)}
```

You need to adjust your totalPages so that it will update once the api call is complete:

```
const [totalPage, setTotalPages] = useState(0);
useEffect(() => {
   setTotalPages(Math.ceil(apiData.length / postsPerPage));
}, [apiData, postsPerPage]);
```

Comment: I tried this, and it doesn't work.. the "next" button won't even show up on page 1

Comment: I've added to the answer.

Comment: Still doesn't work :/

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code help

" maxNumberApiData = apiData.length "

[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-06-t914k3?file=/src/index.jsx)

```
{maxNumberApiData > 1 && pageNumber + 1 <= maxNumberApiData ? (
      <button onClick={() => setPageNumber(pageNumber + 1)}>
        Next page
      </button>
    ) : (
      ""
    )}
```

Comment: this part "maxNumberApiData = apiData.length" doesn't work, the next button doesn't show up on the first page. But when I assign it 10 like in your example code, then it works fine.

Comment: @Sedrido please check the codesandbox again, I think it's working now. let me know about it

Comment: Still not working, the "next" button doesn't come up on the first page

Comment: @Sedrido What's your apiData value and apiData.length ?

Comment: @Payman Li I get my data from here: https://dhis2-app-course.ifi.uio.no/api?

Comment: @Sedrido So is  "total": 215 the number of pages you have? please check the data.json

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248454/discussion-between-peyman-mi-and-sedrido).